# Copying Twitters Style - Integrating Index and Create Form on Same Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'd like to basically do what Twitter's stream does - have the create action and index action available on the same page, but I'm now getting an error, NilClass from the form.

Here's my view, then my code

```
class MistakesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @mistakes = Mistake.all
    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |t|
      t.html
    end
  end

  def create

    @mistake = Mistake.new(params[:mistake])
    @mistake.user = current_user

    respond_to do |f|
      if @mistake.save
        f.html { redirect_to("/", :notice => 'cool') }
      else
        f.html { render :action => 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @new_mistake = Mistake.new
  end

  def show
    @mistake = Mistake.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

and index.html.haml

```
%p test
%p= @user.email
= link_to "Create", new_mistake_path
- semantic_form_for @mistake do |form|
  = form.inputs :name => "Basic" do
    = form.input :message
    = form.input :notes
  = form.inputs :name => "Topics" do
    = form.input
  = form.buttons do
    = form.commit_button
```

I'm starting to go through the growing pains of creating a non-trivial rails app so any help would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:

Error Info

Message

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Occurs when I view index.html.haml.

Comment: Can you post more info about the error? Do you see it when you submit the form or just when you try to view it? What is the output of the error message?

Comment: Edited appropriately, thanks, I'll try to provide that info in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the index action of your controller

```
@mistake = Mistake.new
```

This is required in addition to the @mistakes variable you already have there...

Comment: ps - you may have problems submitting the form unless you add the following code to your create action too: `@mistakes = Mistake.all`. Just bear it in mind

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a *new* action at all, since that form is now part of your index page. I'd recommend just getting rid of that action and having create redirect to index instead.

This is in addition to stephenmurdoch's suggestion above.